# improving program speed: vector speed, memory block speed

Tags: memory, image-processing, vector

i am currently reading 17 images (24 bit, 1200 x 1600). Reading the 17 images costs me about .078 sec However i would like to convert this memory block that is the size of 5760000 into a black and white image size of 192000 to do my laplacian edge_detection. Right now I am using the following method:

```
images.resize(rows * cols);
images.reserve(rows * cols);

for(int z = 0; z < rows * cols; z ++){
    pix.blue = (int) *(pChar + z * 3);
    pix.green = (int) *(pChar + z * 3 + 1);
    pix.red = (int) *(pChar + z * 3 + 2);
    pix.black_white = pix.blue * .11 + pix.green * .59 + pix.red *.3;
    images.at(z).black_white = pix.blue * .11 + pix.green * .59 + pix.red *.3;
}
```

This process however of reading the pChar memory block and writing into a vector size of 1920000 is costing me a total time of 2.262 seconds to read 17 images. Is there a faster way i can approach this?

I have tried using a different code below but the pChar2 keeps on telling me that it has a badptr on debug mode for VS2010: (data_grey, pChar, pChar2 variable is a unsigned char * )

```
pChar = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*3*rows*cols);
pChar2 = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * rows * cols);
fread(pChar, sizeof(char), 3*rows*cols, bmpInput);
images.at(i).data = pChar;

for(int z = 0; z < rows * cols; z ++){
    pix.blue = (int) *(pChar + z * 3);
    pix.green = (int) *(pChar + z * 3 + 1);
    pix.red = (int) *(pChar + z * 3 + 2);
    pix.black_white = pix.blue * .11 + pix.green * .59 + pix.red *.3;
    pChar2 += (unsigned char) pix.black_white;
}
    images.at(i).data_grey = pChar2;
```

My thought is that i may be writing in to the pChar2 memory block in an incorrect manner. But this 2nd method was much faster so i was wondering how i should fix it. It would be ideal if i got a block of memory that is black and white for images.at(i).data_grey. I mostly want to do this cause it was much faster than vectors but is there something i did wrong on the vector based code thats making it so slow in comparison? (i personally find vectors easier to use but if i need speed really badly so i will deal with working with memory blocks if it is supposed to be faster)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you will need to do is change

```
pChar2 += (unsigned char) pix.black_white;
```

to

```
pChar2[z] = (unsigned char) pix.black_white;
```

Assuming you're trying to to what I think you're trying to do (Assign a value to the memory block pChar2 is being pointed at and then move the pointer to the next 8bit memory block?)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the bounds-checking element accessor `at()`.  That will check your index every time, because it must throw an exception if you use an out-of-bounds index.  That should never happen because you resized your vector initially.

So, you should instead use the non-bounds-checking operator `[]`.

You can also write directly into the vector like a C array.  Some purists might get upset about this, but I think it's okay to do with vectors:

```
images.resize(rows*cols);
unsigned char *bwPixel = &images[0];

for( ... )
{
    // ...
    *bwPixel++ = (unsigned char) (pix.blue * .11 + pix.green * .59 + pix.red *.3);
}
```

Comment: thxs for the idea ill change it and see how it changes performance